# How can I politely tell a customer that we only provide e-mail support?

Tags: politeness, business-language

I'm running an online e-commerce site but use only e-mails for customer service to cut the expense.

When a customer asks me by e-mail if he/she can call me for some questions, how can I politely tell her/him to use only e-mail for enquiries?

Is it O.K. to say "*Sorry we accept only e-mail support and don't have phone number*" or something?

Comment: Rather than *accept*, you only *provide* e-mail support.  You only accept *requests* for support via e-mail.

Comment: I suppose (800)GET-LOST would be impolite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say the following, assuming the support is *technical*:

> [Technical] support is only provided via email.

Comment: To me that sounds rather brusque, I wouldn't use it with a customer. The passive voice of "is not provided" implies that the company is evading responsibility for their level of service. 

I'd say "I'm afraid we're not able to provide technical support over the phone, but you're welcome to email us at any time, and we aim to get back to you within 1 working day" (or whatever deadline - the point being to give them an expectation of how long they'll need to wait for a reply to their email).

Answer (score -1):

How about

> Platinum level technical support which includes phone support is available for an additional monthly charge of $x.

Just pick x large enough so that it pays for a telephone line.  If the customer wants it, let him pay for it.

Comment: The telephone line is likely to be the cheapest part of providing telephone support.